# Save item values in recycler view object android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, increment

I am working in recycler view where I have increment and decrement buttons. My condition is that maximum I can't add 10 and minimum 0. When I am clicking on increment button of 1st row item in recycler view it is adding 1, but when I am clicking on 2nd row item in recycler view it is affecting first item of list as well. Lets say item1 becomes 1 plus.

when I am doing any increment and decrement, it should not affect other row items in RecyclerView.

```
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder  holder,final int position) {
    final ParseObject parseObject = arrayList.get(position);
    boolean like = true, dislike = true;
    if (holder instanceof MemberViewHolder) {
        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
            ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtIncrement.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                            counter += 1;
                            ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtCounter.setText(counter+"");
                    }
            });
            ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtDecrement.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if(counter == 0){

                    }else{
                        counter -= 1;
                        ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtCounter.setText(counter+"");
                    }
                }
         });
     }
 }
```

When decrementing from item 1, it is decrementing value in row item2 as well. I want to keep the values per item.

[image]

[image]

Comment: post your onBindViewHolder code

Comment: maintain a array  of counters, size equal to your dataset size, update that index count on decrement and increment  , refer that array for UI updation

Comment: @RahulChaudhary thanks for your reply. I am updating my full onBindViewHolder. Please check it above.

Comment: @VinaySasalatti thanks for your reply. Can you please give me a code snippet as per your explanation. I have edit my onBindViewHolder above, you can check it as well.

Comment: Do you have a list of recyclerview_object for handling each item seprately

Comment: Your `counter` seems to be an Adapter field. It means it's the same for all the rows of your recycler. So each time you change the value it affects all the rows. You need to have a counter per row

Comment: is `counter` variable is `global` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it:

**First create a member variable of type int[]**

```
private int[] counter = new int[10];
```

Here i have given the array a default size of 10 .

**Important:** *This will crash your app if you try to increment item above index 10. To avoid that you need to give it the size of your arrayList when you populate the arrayList (possible in the adapter constructor).*

**Now in your** `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtIncrement.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                    counter[position] += 1;
                    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtCounter.setText(counter[position]+"");

        }
    });
    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtDecrement.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(counter[position] == 0){

            }else{
                counter[position] -= 1;
                ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtCounter.setText(counter[position]+"");
            }
        }
    });                                                   
    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtCounter.setText(counter[position]+"");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your solution perfectly works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a map for this.

`private Map<Integer, Integer> countOfItems = new HashMap<>();`

The key is the position of the item in your adapter. The value is the count of items for that position.

So inside your `onBindViewHolder()` you have to do some changes:

For incrementing:

```
int currentCount = countOfItems.get(position);
currentCount++;
countOfItems.put(position, currentCount);
```

For decrementing:

```
int currentCount = countOfItems.get(position);
if(currentCount > 0) {
  currentCount--;
  countOfItems.put(position, currentCount);
}
```

Initialize your map with count 0 for each item in the contructor of your adapter.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
  countOfItems.put(i, 0)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have run this code, it is give null exception on counter =counterMap.get(position);   On debugger i checked it, it is giving position = 0 and counterMap = 0 and on counterMap.get(position) a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Kindly help me with this

Comment: Do you pass the `arrayList` in adapters constructor or do you set the `arrayList` somewhere else?

Comment: This is my default counter for numbers. I mean I am making numbers from 0 to 10 for add and subtract. I am not taking this 0 to 10 values from server.

Comment: @beep I only want to show 0-10 values if I am pressing Add/subtract button. And that value should be Per Item, it should not affect other row item values.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I think the problem is that the map is not initialized correctly. After you create / assign `arrayList` which includes all `ParseObject` you have to initialized the map like I said. If you modify `arrayList` you also have to modify the map. So for example if you call `arrayList.add(yourNewObject)` you also have to call `countOfItems.put(positionOfNewObject, 0)`. If you remove items from the `arrayList` you also have to remove from the map. Otherwise you have a resource leak.